# Dask LocalCluster Fails to compute random.random above 300Mio data points

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I wanted to create some random data for later benchmarking. The chunks need to be configured this way as I want to calculate the rfft later.

However, the sampling of the random data fails as soon as I am around (and above) 300 million data points. The code works fine in local mode. The code works fine when I store the samples directly into a zarr array.
The size at which the code breaks is consistent across multiple shapes and chunk sizes. It also does not depend on initialising the cluster with different values.

Following is an **minimal example producing the error**, please be advised, that the code is working with an array of `size=(60, 4_000_000)`. However, using the slightly bigger array, leads to error.

```py
cluster = dd.LocalCluster(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=10, memory_limit='30GB')
client = dd.Client(cluster)
# print(client)

RNG_da = da.random.RandomState(42)
_ = RNG_da.random((60, 5_000_000), chunks=(1, 5_000_000)).compute()

client.close()
cluster.close()
```

The same **error** occurs using `LocalCluster()` without parameters:

```py
cluster = dd.LocalCluster() 
client = dd.Client(cluster)

RNG_da = da.random.RandomState(1212)
_ = RNG_da.random((60, 5_000_000), chunks=(1, 5_000_000)).compute()
print(_.shape)
client.close()
cluster.close()
```

However, not specifying or only using the `Client` works. So **all of the versions below work**:

```py
RNG_da = da.random.RandomState(1212)
_ = RNG_da.random((60, 5_000_000), chunks=(1, 5_000_000)).compute()
print(_.shape)
```

```py
client = dd.Client(processes=False)
RNG_da = da.random.RandomState(1212)
_ = RNG_da.random((60, 5_000_000), chunks=(1, 5_000_000)).compute()
print(_.shape)
```

```py
with dask.config.set(scheduler='processes'):
    RNG_da = da.random.RandomState(1212)
    _ = RNG_da.random((60, 5_000_000), chunks=(1, 5_000_000)).compute()
    print(_.shape)
```

```py
with dask.config.set(scheduler='threads'):
    RNG_da = da.random.RandomState(1212)
    _ = RNG_da.random((60, 5_000_000), chunks=(1, 5_000_000)).compute()
    print(_.shape)
```

```py
with dd.LocalCluster(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=10, memory_limit='15GiB') as cluster, dd.Client(cluster) as client:
        RNG_da = da.random.RandomState(1212)
        _ = RNG_da.random((60, 5_000_000), chunks=(1, 5_000_000)).persist()
        print(_.shape)
```

Can it have something to do, with calling the sampling in a multi-processes environment, since using `client = Client(process=True)` results in this `[...]return self.socket.recv_into(buf, len(buf)) OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` error.

---

Here is the error trace, however, I interrupted the program, since it usually runs super long...:

```py
<Client: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:53084' processes=1 threads=10, memory=27.94 GiB>
2023-02-11 18:54:44,007 - distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Couldn't gather keys {"('random_sample-aaf2531c59d5bd1381c467d7a0f0644c', 0, 0)": [‘tcp://127.0.0.1:53089'],

[...]

"('random_sample-aaf2531c59d5bd1381c467d7a0f0644c', 0, 1)": ['tcp://127.0.0.1:53089'], "('random_sample-aaf2531c59d5bd1381c467d7a0f0644c', 2, 1)": ['tcp://127.0.0.1:53089']} state: ['memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory'] workers: ['tcp://127.0.0.1:53089']
NoneType: None
2023-02-11 18:54:44,007 - distributed.worker - ERROR - failed during get data with tcp://127.0.0.1:53089 -> None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/envs/zarr_benchmarking/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 973, in _handle_write
    num_bytes = self.write_to_fd(self._write_buffer.peek(size))
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/envs/zarr_benchmarking/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 1146, in write_to_fd
    return self.socket.send(data)  # type: ignore
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/envs/zarr_benchmarking/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 1768, in get_data
    response = await comm.read(deserializers=serializers)
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/envs/zarr_benchmarking/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 241, in read
    convert_stream_closed_error(self, e)
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/envs/zarr_benchmarking/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 142, in convert_stream_closed_error
    raise CommClosedError(f"in {obj}: {exc.\_\_class\_\_.\_\_name\_\_}: {exc}") from exc
distributed.comm.core.CommClosedError: in <TCP (closed)  local=tcp://127.0.0.1:53089 remote=tcp://127.0.0.1:53096>: ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
2023-02-11 18:54:44,009 - distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Shut down workers that don't have promised key: ['tcp://127.0.0.1:53089'], ('random_sample-aaf2531c59d5bd1381c467d7a0f0644c', 0, 0)
NoneType: None
2023-02-11 18:54:44,009 - distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Shut down workers that don't have promised key: ['tcp://127.0.0.1:53089'], ('random_sample-aaf2531c59d5bd1381c467d7a0f0644c', 6, 2)

[...]

NoneType: None
2023-02-11 18:54:44,011 - distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Shut down workers that don't have promised key: ['tcp://127.0.0.1:53089'], ('random_sample-aaf2531c59d5bd1381c467d7a0f0644c', 2, 1)
NoneType: None
2023-02-11 18:54:44,013 - distributed.client - WARNING - Couldn't gather 21 keys, rescheduling {"('random_sample-aaf2531c59d5bd1381c467d7a0f0644c', 0, 0)": ('tcp://127.0.0.1:53089',), "('random_sample-aaf2531c59d5bd1381c467d7a0f0644c', 6, 2)": ('tcp://127.0.0.1:53089',), "('random_sample-aaf2531c59d5bd1381c467d7a0f0644c', 5, 0)": (‘tcp://127.0.0.1:53089',),

[...]
"('random_sample-aaf2531c59d5bd1381c467d7a0f0644c', 6, 1)": ('tcp://127.0.0.1:53089',), "('random_sample-aaf2531c59d5bd1381c467d7a0f0644c', 0, 1)": ('tcp://127.0.0.1:53089',), "('random_sample-aaf2531c59d5bd1381c467d7a0f0644c', 2, 1)": ('tcp://127.0.0.1:53089',)}

^C
```

---

---

### **EDIT 2**

I did some more testing to try and understand the problem, as I really don't understand why it behaves the way it does. I think I found two important differences, but I can't "understand the puzzle".

**It depends on whether I use `.compute()` or `.persists()`**. Although one should prefer `.persist()` for larger data, I do not understand why it fails with `.compute()`.

**However, the code works regardless of whether I use `.persist()` or `.compute()` if I do not register the client as the default scheduler (`dd.Client(cluster, set_as_default=False)`)**.

```py
with dd.LocalCluster(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=10, memory_limit='15GiB') as cluster, dd.Client(cluster, set_as_default=False) as client:  # if set_as_default=False -> persist and compute work, if True, only persist does work
    RNG_da = da.random.RandomState(1212)
    _ = RNG_da.random((60, 5_000_000), chunks=(1, 5_000_000)).compute()  # .persist() is always working
    print(_)
```

It also *worked* when submitting the data via the client and using `client.compute()`, regardless of whether the client was registered as the default scheduler or not. Whether `pure=False` was set when the data was submitted or not does *not* change whether the program works or not. It also works if the data is not submitted, but only via `client.compute()`.

```py
with dd.LocalCluster(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=10, memory_limit='15GiB') as cluster, dd.Client(cluster, set_as_default=True) as client:
    RNG_da = da.random.RandomState(1212)
    _ = client.submit(RNG_da.random, (60, 5_000_000), chunks=(1, 5_000_000), pure=False)  # working does not depend on pure set false or true
    # also working:
    # _ = RNG_da.random((60, 5_000_000), chunks=(1, 5_000_000))
    # _ = client.compute(_)
    x = _.result()  # if used commented section -> x = _
    print(_)
    print(x)
    del _
    try:
        print(_)
    except NameError:
        print('caught: _ is not defined')
    print(x)  # working and making sure, that persist terminated
```

As a side note (I do not know if this is normal behaviour or not): I found that the client is not really respecting `asynchronous=False` in both the client and the cluster. Both have `self.asynchronous=True` after initialisation.

Perhaps you can understand more from this behaviour. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: You’re calling .compute() on a ~2.5GB array and it’s causing memory problems. Seems like you could just be overwhelming the scheduler or local client. You’ve given the worker a 30GB limit, and that needs to be in addition to the dataset replicated as it passed through the scheduler and into the client. Do you have enough room on your machine? The dask docs recommend you have a few multiples of the dataset size as headroom. Note that when you save to zarr the data is processed in chunks, and the entire array is never held in memory at once.

Comment: If you want to use the chunked array later and simply are testing the cluster spinup, I’d try a reduction operation first, such as `.mean().compute()`

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the fast comment! I have enough space on the local machine (32GB RAM). As pointed out, the problem only occurs in distributed mode. Calling the random call in local mode, works fine, even with array sizes of 60x10.000.000 (~4.8GB) - using the local profiler, the memory spike for the big array is around 11GB. So maybe it is something in the connection between cluster and client?

Comment: The direct saving to zarr works in chunks, but the sampling on the traces as well (?). However, I do see, that the calculations saving to zarr do have a smaller memory footprint. Nevertheless, I want to compute the rfft afterwards, which only allows one chunk in the dimension of the rfft. This works also fine in local mode. But as soon I change to distributed mode, this error occurs.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, I double checked regarding the memory. `_ = RNG_da.randint(0, 10_000, size=(60, 9_000_000), chunks=(1, 9_000_000), dtype=np.int64).compute()` works (in the distributed mode above), so I do not think the major source of the problem is memory on the machine.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by distributed mode?

Comment: Using a cluster and client, instead of "just running" or using a local scheduller.

Comment: Oh ok - if you spin up a client it will create a LocalCluster - can you post a MRE for the case that works as well to demonstrate the difference?

Comment: Only using `RNG_da = da.random.RandomState(42)
_ = RNG_da.random((60, 5_000_000), chunks=(1, 5_000_000)).compute()` without the cluster, client lines before works fine. It really breaks when adding the client & cluster lines.

Comment: Ok. It could just be that you have different defaults and there is a lower maximum array size when using processes compared with threads. When using threads on a local dask cluster the workers can share objects in memory with the client, whereas this is not possible when using a distributed or cluster or when using processes, where objects must be serialized and recreated when passed to/from workers. So from what I can tell this migh still just be consistent with a pattern of running out of memory?

Comment: Hmm, could you give me a hint at which settings/defaults to look? I just checked, `.persists()` works, compute not. Maybe it is a problem communicating back from the cluster to the client - maybe a limit there?

Comment: Persist does exit immediately - did you check to ensure it completes, eg with distributed.wait(persisted) or computing a summary stat on the persisted data? If so then yeah it seems like replicating the data through the scheduler to the client is possibly what’s doing it. The setting I mean is just whether you’re using threads or processes.

Comment: Hi there, just tried the code (distributed mode either with thread or process) that's suppose to be failing on my laptop with 16GB memory, it worked fine. I was able to increase the size of the array a bit. At one point though, my Jupyter kernel crashed from out of memory I suppose, when the array is about 4GiB size. I guess this is just because between the array stored on the workers and the array that gets consolidated and sent back to the client, I ran out of memory, which is normal.

Comment: I'm also a bit puzzled you say it's working with `with dd.LocalCluster(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=10, memory_limit='15GiB') as cluster, dd.Client(cluster) as client:`, as it is basically the same setup as your first example that fails.

Comment: Hi @MichaelDelgado I tried waiting and finishing and it worked. @Guillaume EB Thanks for testing! Strange that it worked for you. To your last comment: The difference is whether I use `.persist()` or `.compute()`. Please see above, the second big edit, to see what else I tested to understand the problem.