# Dask.distributed performance report is not working when Client is not default scheduler

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I just tried to create a performance report for a `Client()` with `LocalCluster`. However, it seems, that the performance report is only working, when the `Client()` is registered as default scheduler (`set_as_default=True`).

```py
import dask.distributed as dd

cluster = dd.LocalCluster(n_workers=2, threads_per_worker=4, memory_limit='5GiB')
client = dd.Client(cluster, set_as_default=False)
    
with dd.performance_report(filename='dask-report.html'):
    print(client)
    print(cluster)
```

Do I miss something?

The following error message is created:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “bla/test.py”, line 9, in <module>
    with dd.performance_report(filename='dask-report.html'):
  File "bla/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 5497, in __enter__
    get_client().sync(self.__aenter__)
  File "bla/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 2771, in get_client
    raise ValueError("No global client found and no address provided")
ValueError: No global client found and no address provided
```

Is there a way to register the scheduler globally?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. Is there a reason to avoid `set_as_default=True`?

Comment: Testing use cases derived from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75422337/dask-localcluster-fails-to-compute-random-random-above-300mio-data-points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a Dask [feature request](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/10004) was created based on this thread, Florian Jetter provided a currently working solution:

> If you don't want to set the client as default, you can also use
> Client.as_current which sets the client as the active default client
> for as long as you are in the contextmanager.

```py
import dask.distributed as dd
    
cluster = dd.LocalCluster(n_workers=2, threads_per_worker=4, memory_limit='5GiB')
client = dd.Client(cluster, set_as_default=False)
        
with client.as_current():
    with dd.performance_report(filename='dask-report.html'):
        print(client)
        print(cluster)
```